# How can we explain the discrepancy between $\rightarrow$ (IF-THEN) and $\setminus$ (A-BUT-NOT-B)?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy

Let $\mathbb{B} = \{0,1\}$ denote the Boolean domain, ordered in the usual way. Then $\mathbb{B}$ is a lattice. It has a join operation $\vee$ that coincides with "OR," a meet operation $\wedge$ that that coincides with "AND," and these distribute over each other. There is also a unique function $\neg : \mathbb{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ subject to the identities $$x \wedge \neg x = 0, \quad x \vee \neg x = 1.$$
This coincides with "NOT." In other words, $\mathbb{B}$ is a Boolean algebra.

We can define two further binary operations (namely $\rightarrow$ and $\setminus$) on $\mathbb{B}$ as follows, coinciding with IF-THEN and A-BUT-NOT-B.

$$x \rightarrow y = \neg x \vee y, \quad x \setminus y = x \wedge \neg y$$

Each is the negation of the other. But there's a HUGE discrepancy in how important and/or ubiquitous these two operations seem to be:

1. Introductory courses in logic and/or mathematics usually talk at length about IF-THEN, but they almost never mention A-BUT-NOT-B.
2. Software proof assistants almost always have support for the IF-THEN operation, but never (as far as I know) have direct support for the A-BUT-NOT-B operation.
3. Almost every theorem in mathematics is phrased using at least one explicit occurrence of IF-THEN, while almost no theorem is ever phrased using an explicit occurrence of A-BUT-NOT-B. This could be a purely linguistic phenomenon, except that:
4. Most mathematicians seem to think of IF-THEN as an actual "stand-alone" operation, yet at the same time, tend to think of A-BUT-NOT-B as a compound operation, built out of AND and NOT.

> **Question.** How can we explain the discrepancy in importance between $\rightarrow$ (IF-THEN) and $\setminus$ (A-BUT-NOT-B)?

I would be satisfied with an explanation of why we tend to think of mathematics asymmetrically *in general,* as opposed to why the asymmetry exists *in this particular case.*

Comment: I think that, for mathematics, the "ubiquitous" presence of $\rightarrow$ is due to the couple of methods of proof involving it : *modus ponens* ($\rightarrow$-elimination) and *Conditional Proof* ($\rightarrow$-introduction) : assume an *hypotheses* and derive a consequence. They are quite "natural" in deductive practice (so much so that most student have difficulties to grasp the difference between the *conditional* and the relation of *entailment* or *logical consequence*).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, its worth noting from a lattice-theoretic viewpoint, Conditional Proof is the statement "$x \wedge y \leq z$ implies $x \leq y \rightarrow z$" and modus ponens is the converse. But observe that "$x \wedge y \leq z$ implies $x \leq y \rightarrow z$" is basically dual to the statement "$z \leq x \vee y$ implies $z \setminus x \leq y$." So there ARE versions of modus ponens (etc.) that apply to $\setminus$. I see your point though; ordinary mathematical practice seems not to adopt the symmetrical lattice-theoretic viewpoint. I guess the question, then, is why not?

Comment: While well formulated, this question seems to be about behavior and language rather than math. There is probably not a definitive answer, and certainly not a mathematical one :(

Comment: Counter-question: why would anyone expect symmetric behavior? Doesn't that just lead to entire classes of superfluous ways to express a single statement? It's not surprising if most people stick to a single way they're familiar with.

Comment: @rschwieb, thanks for your comments. Even if the question does not admit a fully mathematical answer, I think this is a genuinely important question. Suppose you're designing a proof assistant for classical mathematics. Should your language just include AND, OR, NOT and IFF? Should it also include IF-THEN and A-BUT-NOT-B? Perhaps just IF-THEN? If just IF-THEN, why? I think Mauro's comment may be on the right track. If the proof assistant makes use of something resembling natural deduction, then $\rightarrow$ is perhaps going to be more important than $\setminus$.

Comment: Neither this operator nor any equivalent is listed in "List of Logic Symbols" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols Could it be merely a quirk of one particular presentation or subspecialty?

Comment: Well, it may be a *curious* question, but it's hard to say that it's an *important* question. I don't recall ever seeing any books or students struggling with the absence of this. For example, I know of a special type of quadrilateral (defined by "one diagonal bisects the other") that fills a gap in an 8 node diagram to create a very appealing 9 node diagram of quadrilaterals. The missing node is interesting with respect to that, but it's not interesting otherwise, and hardly surprising people ignore it.

Comment: Why would you need an operator that is just the negation of implication?

Comment: @DanChristensen +1 That's the most apt description of what I've been feeling since the beginning of this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table of your "A-BUT-NOT-B", which I'll call "[L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_nonimplication)" with "0" for falsity and "1" for truth goes as follows:

```
L  0  1
0  0  0
1  1  0
```

Do any tautologies with just "L" exist?  I'm not sure how to argue that none exist, but I'll guess that NO tautologies with "L" exist.  Thus, we can't infer anything from any statement where the only connective is "L".  On the other hand, there do exist tautologies with "C" (if-then).  If there do not exist any L-tautologies, then there are no proofs where L is the primary connective involved in inferring to the last theorem of the proof.  On the other hand, there exist plenty of proofs which use some sort of "C" connective.

Comment: This is an interesting point. "C" has many useful tautologies, while "L" as has many contradictions. E.g. $A \rightarrow A$ is a tautology, while $A \setminus A$ is a contradiction. So perhaps the preference for "C" stems from a preference for tautologies over contradictions.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematicians use "A but not B" every time they provide a counterexample. This is a direct consequence of it being the negation of "A implies B."

An implication gives rise to at least one counterexample, so this structure is actually being used implicitly a good portion of the time when authors supply counterexamples.

The reasons for its absence as a formal "thing" and the reasons for preferring to emphasize "implies" are probably just a combination of tradition and habit. There is seemingly no need to elevate the importance of the negation of a particular construct to be equal with the construct.